# ajax call to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get rows that match a var, In my case a url. in the database and return the whole row as a json format.

Basically if url in table1 matches the url under eventurl in table2. Then the whole row is passed through to the ajax request as a jsonformat.

Heres what i have so far.

Routes.rb

```
resources :gig do
    scope constraints: { format: "json" } do
      get :gigdata, on: :member
    end
  end
```

In my ajax call i have this

```
url: 'gigdata/' + gigurlofevent , (no need to include the whole url ajax file here as its working elsewhere)
```

and in my controller i have this

```
  respond_to :json, only: :gigdata
   def gigdata
    gig = Gigstable.where(eventurl: (params[:gigurlofevent]))
    render json: gig
   end
```

Now at the moment, I can't get into the gigdata with a byebug.

I'm wondering what i need to do/ what ive missed

Thanks
Sam

**edit**

Heres the start of the ajax call down the the success function

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'gigdata/' + gigurlofevent ,
        success: function(json) {
            debugger;
```

Comment: what is the url your are hitting on from the ajax request ?

Comment: @OmarMowafi Its hitting `localhost:8000/event/gigdata/gigurlofevent` the urlofevent includes a http tag which may mess things up?

Answer (score 0):

### Common problem:

You wrote:

> (no need to include the whole url ajax file here as its working
> elsewhere)

Actually you need to include complete code because common problem lays in `Content-Type` field. You need to specify content type of request in header like 'application/json'.

I am testing my backend api with `curl`
For example:

```
curl http://localhost/api/v1/some_action -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -vvv
```

Last parameter `-vvv` very useful to debug requests because it makes curl to output request and response with headers in console.

### Another way to debug ajax

Open developer tools (for chrome it's: <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>), click on network tab and click on XHR filter button. Reload page with `ctrl+r` and execute your ajax request one more time. Information about your ajax request will appear in the window below filters. Now you can check out what kind of data comes from server and whats going wrong.

### Golden rule

Rails server outputs all requests in console. Don't be shy to read output when something works not like you expected.

Comment: Okay, I'll add the whole ajax call in for you now.

Comment: @SamRoberts looks like your ajax code ok. Updated my answer

Comment: @SamRoberts check out url and request header. Also check out rails console output. Mostly looks like problem in url but make sure that rails trying to response with json, not html.

Comment: i cant check if its passing through as json or html as i dont have the righturl.